# Selfhosted gitlab, CI docker login fails with the message denied: access forbidden

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

From my local PC, I can login fine into the Repo, but when I try to log in from within the CI in gitlab, it always fails with the message `denied: access forbidden`.

This is the output from the CI:

```
-----
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.domain.nl:5002/v2/: denied: access forbidden

----
```

This is my project file:

```
# Official docker image.
image: docker:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

build-master:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN gitlab.domain.nl:5002
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to reformat your question, so that code is rendered properly. You can do that by indenting in by four (additional) spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting :)

Comment: Just to make sure: `gitlab.domain.nl:5002` is the registry of the gitlab instance running the CI? To make this more portable, you could use `$CI_REGISTRY` instead of the hard-coded domian.

Comment: Well even when im using $CI_REGISTRY it dous not work,
And yes the gitlab instance is running the registry 
The link is correct (domain) Isnt the real domain but its private so i just replaced it when posting here

Comment: I can docker login fine into the registry  from my pc, But just not from the CI

Answer (score 1):

If your GitLab instance is up to date, you should use the `CI_REGISTRY_*` variables for all parts of the `docker login …`.

```
docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
```

See [GitLab CI/CD Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) for details.

Comment: Well same result with that exact command, an instant  denied: access forbidden
I readed something online that it's with an certificate somwhere?, But i can't figure that out sadley

Answer (score 1):

Ideally the answer is the same as mentioned above

`docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY`

But i have encountered the issue from docker registry side. Make sure your registry is configured with valid ssl certificate. https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#get-a-certificate.

Check with 
`curl https://<$CI_REGISTRY>/v2/`

Which should return
`{}`

And you should also need to add this variable in Project settings.

`DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` : `<paste the contents of ~/.docker/config.json>`

I think this should solve the issue.